# AX Spin system ordering

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

I would like to ask a question about the ordering of the $\ce{X}$ spins on the right hand side of an $\ce{AX2}$ energy diagram.

I was given the diagram here below:

[image]

and asked to evaluate why this diagram results in a triplet. This is simple, since there are 4 possible energy transitions, but one of them is equivalent to the singlet transition, hence only 3 transitions would appear in the NMR spectrum.

Prior to this though, I was confused because I thought the ordering for the bottom 3 spins was incorrect. Taking $\ce{\alpha}$ as the lower energy spin, I thought the bottom 3 spins should read as:

$$\begin{align}&\beta \beta \\
 \beta \alpha &~~~~ \alpha \beta \\
 &\alpha \alpha \end{align}$$

and the energy levels would be drawn more appropriately. 
I attempted but failed to mention this to the lecturer during the presentation.

Am I correct in this instance?

Comment: Neither of those diagrams make sense afai can tell. How can you have a transition that doesnt flip *any* spins?

Comment: @BuckThorn I questioned whether the order of the bottom 3 spins was incorrect but I did think about the selection rule and why that was not obeyed in this slide

Comment: @BuckThorn it is flipping the A spin. The A spin state is on the left. The X spin states (which don’t flip) are on the right.

Comment: @orthocresol Gotcha, I misread the diagram.

Comment: @BuckThorn that was a minor point, though. You are quite correct that the diagram is wrong in many ways. It is not a physically accurate description of coupling. The diagram implies that the splitting between the peaks in the triplet has a frequency on the order of an X spin flip, which is completely... well... off.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that seem to be wrong with the diagram you present, but since your focus is on the relative energies of the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ spin states I'll address only this. If you check a reliable source such as Cavanagh et al.s NMR textbook [ref 1] it is explained that

> the state with $m=+\frac{1}{2}$ is referred to as the $\alpha$ state, and the state with $m=-\frac{1}{2}$ is referred to as the $\beta$ state.  If $\gamma$ [the gyromagnetic ratio] is positive, then the $\alpha$ state has lower energy than the $\beta$ state.

Therefore for protons $\alpha$ is lower energy (since $\gamma>0$). If the nucleus is $\ce{^{15}N}$ ($\gamma<0$), $\beta$ becomes the lower energy state.

So while your concern is valid, it is a relatively minor flaw (in my opinion) with the diagram. Good for you for noticing it.

*Reference*

1. John Cavanagh, Nicholas Skelton, Wayne Fairbrother, Mark Rance, Arthur Palmer, III. Protein NMR Spectroscopy, Principles and Practice, 2nd Edition. Academic Press, 2006, ISBN: 9780121644918.